# Responsive html/css table with fixed row height text-overflow ellipsis vertically aligned

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, html-table

I am trying to create a bootstrap responsive table with fixed row height (images will vertically stretch to fit), text cells vertically aligned and text in one single line showing ellipses if there is overflow.

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ernestbofill/nnswbycw/1/) show what I have achieved so far.

In chrome (have not tried other browsers) the image thumbnail ignores the `height` assigned to the entire row. I don't know how to vertically center the text either and how to force the table to horizontally fit in the page with no horizontal scroll showing ellipses on the text fields if needed.

The image represents how I would like it to be like:
[image: row concept]

HTML:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table" id="list-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td><input class="toggle-all" type="checkbox" /></td>
                <td>Thumbnail</td>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td class="link-margin"></td>
                <td>Description</td>
                <td>Category</td>
                <td>Type</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="list-content-row">
                <td><input class="select-product" type="checkbox" /></td>
                <td class="img">
                    <div><img class="img-responsive product-img" src="http://www.mildred.co/issueassets/22/14RSowlhat.jpg"/></div>
                </td>
                <td><div><a href="#">Lorem ex amet</a></div></td>
                <td class="link-margin"></td>
                <td><div>Aute esse ullamco fugiat amet dolore fugiat proident in mollit. Veniam minim in enim consequat nulla velit.</div></td>
                <td><div>music</div></td>
                <td><div>Video (mp4)</div></td>
            </tr>            
            <tr class="list-content-row">
                <td><input class="select-product" type="checkbox" /></td>
                <td class="img">
                    <div><img class="img-responsive product-img" src="http://www.dncompute.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2008/03/dice.jpg"/></div>
                </td>
                <td><div><a href="#">ex qui do</a></div></td>
                <td class="link-margin"></td>
                <td><div>Cillum sunt irure minim commodo et ipsum. Nisi elit occaecat officia dolore eu culpa quis.</div></td>
                <td><div>films</div></td>
                <td><div>Image (gif)</div></td>
            </tr>            
            <tr class="list-content-row">
                <td><input class="select-product" type="checkbox" /></td>
                <td class="img">
                    <div><img class="img-responsive product-img" src="http://zoarchurch.co.uk/content/pages/uploaded_images/91.png"/></div>
                </td>
                <td><div><a href="#">esse Lorem consequat</a></div></td>
                <td class="link-margin"></td>
                <td><div>Officia fugiat consequat officia aliquip sit consectetur eu. Non laborum aliquip cillum ipsum consectetur.</div></td>
                <td><div>music</div></td>
                <td><div>Image (png)</div></td>
            </tr>            
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.table .link-margin {
  padding: 0;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
.table tbody tr {
  height: 30px;
}
.table tbody tr td > div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.table tbody tr td > div img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Include this CSS as well:

```
.img div
{
    max-height:50px !important;
}
```

Comment: for responsiveness use `max-height:3em` and `1em = 16 px`